# jquery trigger focus does not work in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, triggers, safari, focus

I have a form in my website and I fill all the fields from get request variables. In 2 of input field I am executing google maps app in order to calculate distance.

When I am reading the values from request, I want to trigger focus event in order to automatically call gmaps app and calculate distance. The trigger function SOMETIMES does not working in chrome and in safari although it always works in Firefox, explorer and edge. I am trying to set a timeout but the problem continues to exist.

My code

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#option_31').trigger("focus");
    $('#option_31').on("focus", function(){
        //do staff
    });
    $('#option_32').trigger("focus");
    $('#option_32').on("focus", function(){
        //do staff
    });
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to trigger the timeout before the event handlers are set. 
Some browsers on some platforms might be so slow in triggering or so fast in setting the event handler, that your code works there

It is better to not set the event handlers inside the timeout at all:

```
$('#option_31').on("focus", function(){
    //do stuff
});     
$('#option_32').on("focus", function(){
    //do stuff
});

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#option_31').trigger("focus");
  $('#option_32').trigger("focus");
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Don't forget to put your code inside the  `$(function(){ your code })` to be sure it will be executed when DOM is ready